# Official Twitter follow button code does not pass validator

Tags: html, twitter, validation, twitter-follow

I ran my website through [Validator](http://validator.w3.org) and it returned two errors, both of which relating to the official Twitter follow button code.

The code for the larger button is:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/gary" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @gary</a>

<script type="text/javascript">!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Validator returned these errors when checking my site as XHTML 1.0 Transitional:

```
there is no attribute "data-show-count"
```

and

```
there is no attribute "data-size"
```

**So what is the deal here?** Obviously these two attributes exists. Removing the data-size will return the smaller version of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with HTML5 Doctype.

Comment: Well you probably used a doctype like XHTML 1.0 strict right? Change that with the HTML 5 Doctype : http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp